# Go and COM/ActiveX

Tags: windows, activex, go

Can anyone point me toward a Go library that will give me the ability to make early- and/or late- bound calls to COM/ActiveX objects in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps https://github.com/mattn/go-ole ?